# C# Linq/Lambda searching for items in related table but not in viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query in my controller

```
data = (from item in dbContext.Documents
    join dc in dbContext.DocumentCategories
    on item.DocumentCategoriesId equals dc.Id
    join df in dbContext.DocumentFields
    on dc.Id equals df.DocumentCategoriesId
    join dfs in dbContext.DocumentFieldsStore
    on df.Id equals dfs.DocumentFieldsId
    where (df.DocumentCategoriesId == FilterInput.CategoryId ||
    df.Id == FilterInput.FieldId) || dfs.Data.Contains(FilterInput.Data)

    select new DocumentsListViewModel
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Name = item.Name,
        ApplicationName = item.ApplicationName,
        ApplicationSecretKey = item.ApplicationSecretKey,
        Link = item.Link,
        Location = item.Location,
        FileType = item.FileType,
        CreatedOn = item.CreatedOn
    }).ToList();
```

My intention is to search for data in the DocumentFieldsStore table that is connected to the DocumentFields table which is connected to the DocumentCategories table which is then connected to the Documents table.

Currently, I am getting duplicate results. How can I add distinct to this query?

Also there is another version of this query that is like this:

```
data = (from item in dbContext.Documents
    join dc in dbContext.DocumentCategories
    on item.DocumentCategoriesId equals dc.Id
    join df in dbContext.DocumentFields
    on dc.Id equals df.DocumentCategoriesId
    join dfs in dbContext.DocumentFieldsStore
    on df.Id equals dfs.DocumentFieldsId
    select new DocumentsListViewModel
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Name = item.Name,
        ApplicationName = item.ApplicationName,
        ApplicationSecretKey = item.ApplicationSecretKey,
        Link = item.Link,
        Location = item.Location,
        FileType = item.FileType,
        CreatedOn = item.CreatedOn
    }).Where(
        u => u.DocumentCategory.Contains(FilterInput.CategoryId) &&
        u.DocumentFields.Contains(FilterInput.FieldId) 
    ).ToList();
```

However, I am unable to access the DocumentFields, DocumentFieldsStore, DocumentCategories tables and am only limited to the viewmodel.

Which version should I use?

Comment: About the **distinct** question: you could add a call to the Distinct() set operator method (cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2). But you should ask yourself **why** are you getting duplicates in the first place? Maybe you are missing some conditions in your join or maybe you need to cleanup your database (and add proper keys to prevent those duplicates from happening).

Comment: About the **which query** question: I think they are equivalent (Linq is quite smart in its optimization; the actual database query is performed when you do ToList, so both versions will have the same performance I think), but the first one makes a bit more sense: **first filter the data, then project the results to your viewmodel**.

Comment: I'm getting duplicates because I'm searching in tables with a one to many relationship

Comment: You could use a subquery to select the related data that you need. E.g. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/10/01/subqueries-in-linq.aspx

Comment: You could convert everything to a string and then use Distinct : var distinct = data.Select(x => new string[] {x.Id.ToString(), x.Name, x.ApplicationName, x.ApplicationSecretKey.ToString(), x.Link.ToString(), x.FileType.ToString(), x.CreatedOn.ToString()}).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this data.distinct(u => u.Id).where(u => u.id == Input.Id)?